# Past continuous in reported speech

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, reported-speech

I am confused with present continous tense in reported speech do we need backshifting or not ? and if we do backshifting should we backshift the second part of the sentences? ( "when" part )

He said ‘I was having breakfast when you phoned me.’

1- He said that he was having breakfast when I phoned him.

2- He said that he had been having breakfast when I phoned him.

3- He said that he had been having breakfast when I had phoned him.

Which sentences should I use in reported speech ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native speaker, but judging by the following examples, it looks like the number 2 is the right one.

Barbara said, “I didn’t realise it was midnight.”
 **Barbara said she hadn’t realised it was midnight.**

"I was waiting for the bus when he arrived."
**She said that she had been waiting for the bus when he arrived.**

I hadn't travelled by underground before I came to London."
**She said that she hadn't travelled by underground before she came to London.**

I was sleeping when Julie called."
**She said that she had been sleeping when Julie called.**

Comment: Yes, number 2 is the correct choice here.